# Is it possible to determine what operating system an email was sent from?

Tags: email, operating-systems

Is it possible to determine what OS an email was sent from? I'm hoping it would be more probable if it is sent from an email client? I don't need specific details on the OS, just whether it is Mac, Linux, Windows, etc.

Comment: It may be possible to tell from the `User-Agent` mail header - but this can be spoofed ... without the mail headers it is impossible to tell ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: NO, you can not tell.

But sometimes you can. Have a look at the headers and look for something like: `X-Mailer:` if it says something like `X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 15.0` it is probably Windows. But these headers can be spoofed easily.